# XCode bit array: selectedSegmentIndex to decimal

Tags: objective-c

so I have three selectedSegmentIndex. Let's call them S1, S2, S3.

They are in order going from left to right, each with an index of 2 (0 and 1). I would like to convert the chosen index for each segment and convert them to an integer. For example:

```
S1.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
S2.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
S3.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
```

This represents 011 in binary or 3 in decimal. Going from selectedSegmentIndex to decimal is easy because you just add them up: S1.selectedSegmentIndex*4 + S2.selectedSegmentIndex*2 + S3.selectedSegmentIndex, which yields 3. The part that I'm having trouble with is going from an integer and fill out these three selectedSegmentIndex. Anyone want to take a stab at this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `>>` to get the desired bit into position 0, and then use `&` to turn off all the other bits.

```
s1.selectedSegmentIndex = (bits >> 2) & 1;
s2.selectedSegmentIndex = (bits >> 1) & 1;
s3.selectedSegmentIndex = (bits >> 0) & 1;
```